# Unity SceneView rotation 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing an 3D Game from Unity but the editor is 2D, game is 3D. Can someone help?
Here is the error: `SceneView rotation is fixed to identity when in 2D mode. This will be an error in future versions of Unity. UnityEditor.GenericMenu:CatchMenu (object,string[],int) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/GenericMenu.cs:125)`

Here is the screenshots between Game and Editor:

Game:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987788339023327302/1003605137350217859/Ekran_Resmi_2022-08-01_13.07.29.png

Editor:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987788339023327302/1003605151354990745/Ekran_Resmi_2022-08-01_13.06.48.png

Comment: Change the view. It will say 2d. Click and change to 3d

Answer (score 0):

I think your scene view options are blocked by the toolkit.
From there you need to unpress the 2D button.

Scene view options

[image]